# Will App preview video for iPhone 5 be the first item on iPhone 6(+) app store

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, iphone

We have submitted an app preview video, recorded using an iPhone 5 along with our new binary. We have also gotten some screenshots for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus using the simulator.

My question is, will users who use iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus see the app preview video for iPhone 5 as the first element when they look for our app or will they see the first iPhone 6 screenshot?

Comment: Do you solve your problem?

Comment: @Scott yes we did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have an iPhone 6 and can verify that with the current version of iOS (8.1), the user will see the app preview video as the first element.

Comment: We don't have iPhone 6 & 6+ and try to find how to solve this problem. It seems that buying a new iPhone is best solution. XD